# Switch back to root after switching using SU

Tags: ubuntu, su

I connect to my Ubuntu EC2 instance over SSH and authenticate using a private key.

I am in the process of installing Cowrie on my Ubuntu instance and as per the instructions here: https://cowrie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL.html I create a non-root user using the following command:

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password <userName>
```

Once created, I then switch using `su - <userName>`

My question is, how do I leave this shell using my non-root account and return to my root account? At the moment I'm exiting the entire SSH session but this doesn't feel like the most efficient path to take.

Answer (score 2):

As [jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) commented, your `su` command simply entered into another shell as that username; typing `exit` will leave that shell and return you to your root shell.